# Binding JSON data in Angular

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, ember.js, jsonp

I'm evaluating JS frameworks to use for a project and I'm stuck between Angular and Ember.  Before I finish my evaluation of Angular, I need to know if there is an easy way to bind data to an external json file stored on S3.

My use case is to create a scoreboard using data that will be published live to S3 periodically... usually ever 15 seconds or so.

Right now, I'm just creating a basic scoreboard page with data from a local json file, but is there a way to make the data in index.html update when the json file changes or am I stuck with having to make some sort of callback?

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks!

```
// app.js
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.controller('ScoreboardCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('scoreboard.json')
    .then(function(res){
      // Storing the json data object as 'scores'
      $scope.scores = res.data;
    });
});
```

The idea is to create a scoreboard by cycling through scores:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="App" >
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>LIVE</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="ScoreboardCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="score in scores">
      {{score.home_team_score}} - {{score.away_team_score}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

> is there a way to make the data in index.html update when the json file changes

It should do that already. If you change `$scope.scores` the view is going to be updated.

If you need to update it from the live server, just set a timer using `setInterval` (or the $timeout service) and do the `$http.get` call at regular intervals.